# How do you pass a vectors return type when your calling a function?

Tags: c++, function, vector, parameter-passing

*IDE that I'm using : Code::Blocks 16.01|Compiler that I'm  using : MingGW GCC 6.3.0*

**Title:**
How do you pass a vectors return type when your calling a function?

**Problem(s):**
I'm trying to to pass the size of a vector called pi as a parameter in the print function by using the pi.size() function but gives me an error message. Tried different ways to correct it but to no avail.

**Error(s):**

Build Messages:
v4 - Vectors\main.cpp|18|error: call of overloaded 'print(std::vector::size_type)' is ambiguous|

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "../Library/mainLibrary.h"
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

vector<double> pi(5,3.14);
print(pi.size());
cout << pi.size() << endl;
cout << pi.capacity() << endl;
print(pi[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

**mainLibrary.h**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

#ifndef MAINLIBRARY_H_INCLUDED
#define MAINLIBRARY_H_INCLUDED

void functionName(char input[], int status);

//Prints to screen using overloaded functions
void print(int input);
void print(int*& input);
void print(long input);
void print(double input);
void print(char input);
void print(const char* input);
void print(string input);
void print(string* input);
#endif // MAINLIBRARY_H_INCLUDED
```

**mainLibrary.cpp**

```
#include <iostream> //used for cin, cout
#include "mainLibrary.h"
#include <string> // used for string functions
#include <cstdlib> // used for system function calls

using namespace std;

int functionNameFlag = 0;

void functionName(char input[],int status)
{
    if (functionNameFlag == 1 && status == 1)
    {
        cout << "\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n";
        cout << "Entering function : " << input <<  "\n";
        cout << "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n";
    }
    if (functionNameFlag == 1 && status == 2)
    {
        cout << "\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n";
        cout << "Exiting function : " << input <<  "\n";
        cout << "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n";
    }
    ;

//    functionName(currentFunctionName, 2);
}

void print(int input)
{
    char currentFunctionName[] = "void print(int input)";
    functionName(currentFunctionName, 1);

    cout << input << endl;

    functionName(currentFunctionName, 2);
}

void print(int*& input)
{
    char currentFunctionName[] = "void print(int*& input)";
    functionName(currentFunctionName, 1);

    cout << input << endl;

    functionName(currentFunctionName, 2);
}

void print(long input)
{
    char currentFunctionName[] = "void print(long input)";
    functionName(currentFunctionName, 1);

    cout << input << endl;

    functionName(currentFunctionName, 2);
}

void print(double input)
{
    char currentFunctionName[] = "void print(double input)";
    functionName(currentFunctionName, 1);

    cout << input << endl;

    functionName(currentFunctionName, 2);
}

void print(char input)
{
    char currentFunctionName[] = "void print(char input)";
    functionName(currentFunctionName, 1);

    cout << input << endl;

    functionName(currentFunctionName, 2);
}

void print(const char* input)
{
    char currentFunctionName[] = "void print(const char* input)";
    functionName(currentFunctionName, 1);

    cout << input << endl;

    functionName(currentFunctionName, 2);
}

void print(string input)
{
    char currentFunctionName[] = "void print(string input)";
    functionName(currentFunctionName, 1);

    cout << input << endl;

    functionName(currentFunctionName, 2);
}

void print(string* input)
{
    char currentFunctionName[] = "void print(string* input)";
    functionName(currentFunctionName, 1);

    cout << input << endl;

    functionName(currentFunctionName, 2);
}
```

Comment: What is a "vector's return type"?

Comment: Looks like it's because `size` returns a `size_type`, you don't have an overload that specifically handles that type, and multiple overloads use possible castable types.

Comment: I urge you to ponder the **minimal** aspect of a [mcve].

Comment: Why do you need all these `print` functions if 1) there is `std::cout`; 2) you could use templates to write only one function instead of a hundred?

Comment: ForceBru - Don't know about creating templates yet. I know how to make overloaded functions so depending on what datatypes your using the program will use a specific one.

Comment: Story Teller - I already read the Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example page, and reduced the program to what is relevant. I also reduced mainLibrary to only the print functions since I thought they were relevant. To include everything thing else would make it more difficult to read.

Comment: Heaven forbid including anything else. You really didn't have to separate it into translation units, for one. And all those comments... ugh. It wasn't minimal, that's my point.

Comment: juanchopanza - a vectors return type is when you use one of the vectors built in functions, such as 'vector_name.size()', when it exit's it's function, it will return a value to the calling program. What you do with this value is totally up to you.

Comment: StoryTeller - Thanks for you feedback. What do you mean by translation units?

Comment: [What is a “translation unit” in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106149/what-is-a-translation-unit-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

Your program doesn't know which `print()` function to call, it could call `print(int input)` or `print(long input)` or ...

To help it decide, you can cast the result from `size()` like so:

```
print((int)pi.size());
```

Watch out though, if `size()` is really big, then casting to `int` would be insufficient. You might want to cast to `long` instead (thanks Jesper Juhl), or create another `print()` function that takes in an `unsigned int` argument.

Comment: <frslm> - Thanks, it worked doing it by your method that you gave. I was also wondering if there's also a way to add a new overloaded print function that will handle vectors and arrays without casting it in the calling program.

Comment: Sure, you could define `void print(size_t input);`. That way, you can call `print(pi.size());` without needing to cast anything.

Comment: <frslm> - Your idea worked by adding 'void print(size_t input)'. I'm relatively new at C++. There's a lot to learn.